# Filtering controls on subforms after selecting criteria from another form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have three subforms I'd like to filter - we'll call them Customers, Items and Employees. I want to sort them based on a 4th form, Addresses, after double-clicking on the Address_ID. So essentially disable those forms until an Address_ID is selected and then populate them based on the given address.

The trouble is that I'm not sure where or what to code. I would assume that I need to create a Double_Click event on the Address_ID control. Maybe store that ID into a variable and somehow pass it to the parent form where the other 3 forms can reference it?

Problem is I have no idea how to accomplish that or if it will work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can a Form_Current event on the address sub form and update the recordsources (not recordset) from each of the subforms.  This is my personally my preferred approach, but there a plethora of options available to approach this situation.  Here's a sample code on how you could approach this.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim addressID As Integer
    Dim sql As String

    If IsNull(Me.addressID.Value) Then

        'disable subforms
        Form_frmHome.sbfCustomer.Enabled = False
        Form_frmHome.sbfEmployee.Enabled = False
        Form_frmHome.sbfItem.Enabled = False

    Else

        'enable subforms
        Form_frmHome.sbfCustomer.Enabled = True
        Form_frmHome.sbfEmployee.Enabled = True
        Form_frmHome.sbfItem.Enabled = True

         addressID = Me.addressID.Value

         'Customers
         sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WHERE AddressID = " & addressID
         Form_frmHome.sbfCustomer.Form.RecordSource = sql

         'Employees
         sql = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE AddressID = " & addressID
         Form_frmHome.sbfEmployee.Form.RecordSource = sql

         'Items
         sql = "SELECT * FROM tblItems WHERE AddressID = " & addressID
         Form_frmHome.sbfItem.Form.RecordSource = sql

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Expand the Master/Link child fields of the three subform controls to include the Address_ID of the fourth:

```
[NameOfTheFourthSubformControl].Form!Address_ID
```

and the three subforms will be filtered automatically (zero code) to the current Address_ID.

*NameOfTheFourthSubformControl* is the *control* on the parent form, not the name of the subform itself.